# Iterate a CodeIgniter database result object with Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

so i need your help. In Codeigniter my model returns a database result object(not a result array) to my controller, and i want to iterate this object with Ajax. Any advise how should i do that? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

1 - [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) the object and output it to the client.

2 - Loop over the received object via [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) within your ajax method's success callback.